# Returning an object based on __class__.__name__ in Python

Tags: python

So I have a Superclass (which for simplicity I'll call), Mammal, from which classes Dog, Monkey, and Bear inherit methods.  Some of the inherited methods return an object that needs to be of the same class it is called from.  For example, `Dog.find(...)` should return Dog objects. But because the `find()` method is inherited from Mammal, the method can't be coded to explicitly `return Dog(...)`.  It would need to be able to return Dog, Monkey, Bear, or Mammal objects, depending on the value of `self.__class__.__name__`.

I've achieved this with `return eval(self.__class__.__name__)(...)`, but I'd prefer to avoid using eval. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why exactly would you ask a Dog in order to find another Dog? What is the process by which the return value is determined? (Is 'find' really a reasonable name for the method?)

Comment: That's a good point. I'll agree it's a little awkward.  It's basically a model from an MVC framework.  I can instantiate Dog objects from rows of a DB table, do things like `dog.name = 'Rex'` and then `dog.save()` to update it in the table. This leaves me needing a class that can return Dog objects based on find conditions, but I feel like this is too specialized for the DB wrapper class to do.  I'm not the best at class design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try `return self.__class__()`

Comment: Ok that works.  Not sure why I didn't think of that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [classmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) to make a factory:

```
class Mammal(object):

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, *args, **kwds):
        return cls(*args, **kwds)

class Dog(Mammal):

    def find(self):
        return self.new()

>>> d = Dog()
>>> d2 = d.find()
>>> type(d2)
<class '__main__.Dog'>
```

Comment: Didn't know about @classmethod.  I'll keep this in mind.  The other answer fits better with what I have already, but I'll try this next time.

Comment: @nren Yes, but this fits much better with my understanding of what you're really trying to do :)